# How to display Localized days of the week in CollectionView in Swift? iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was just making a weather app that displays 5-day weather temperatures. And the problem that I have right now is **how do I display weekdays that are retrieved dynamically on my Collection View?** They are well displaying in English, but I want them to be in Russian. The source is given below:

**This is the code that is in my `cellForItemAt` function**

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE")
let actualDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
cell.dayCollection.text = String(NSLocalizedString("%@", comment: "displaying weekdays"), actualDate) // see this line
return cell
```

**This is my Localizable.string file:**

```
"%@" = "Воскресенье";
"%@" = "Понедельник";
"%@" = "Вторник";
"%@" = "Среда";
"%@" = "Четверг";
"%@" = "Пятница";
"%@" = "Суббота";
```

Please let me know if you need any other source or answer. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Localized.string` file should be

```
"Sunday" = "Воскресенье";
"Monday" = "Понедельник";
"Tuesday" = "Вторник";
"Wednesday" = "Среда";
"Thursday" = "Четверг";
"Friday" = "Пятница";
"Saturday" = "Суббота";
```

and

```
let day = NSLocalizedString(actualDate, comment: "")
cell.dayCollection.text = day
```

---

### Update for displaying "Today" as current day

Create `Extension+Date.swift` file first. Add code below into the file.

```
extension Date {
        /// Compare self with another date.
        ///
        /// - Parameter anotherDate: The another date to compare as Date.
        /// - Returns: Returns true if is same day, otherwise false.
        public func isSame(_ anotherDate: Date) -> Bool {
            let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
            let componentsSelf = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
            let componentsAnotherDate = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: anotherDate)
            
            return componentsSelf.year == componentsAnotherDate.year && componentsSelf.month == componentsAnotherDate.month && componentsSelf.day == componentsAnotherDate.day
        }
}
```

At your `cellForRow` modify to:

```
var actualDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
if date.isSame(Date()) {
    actualDate = "Today"
}
```

Add `Today` key in your `Localized.string` file

```
"Today" = "Cегодня";
```

Comment: Can we put a variable inside `NSLocalizedString()` ?

Comment: It works just amazing! One more thing, how can I make the current day equal to "today" but also in russian?

Comment: let me check this out

Comment: excuse me, but what does `self` mean here? It says in `...from: self` cannot convert. I guess we should put `Date()` right?

Comment: it also says in `cellForRow` `Value of type 'Date' has no member 'isSame'`

Comment: oh sorry. The isSame function should be placed in extension Date { /*here*/ }

Comment: Yeah, it works but it only displays "today" in my `CollectionView`. Please help with this, hope this is the last question.:))

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it this time. Can you provide screen cap of code and output?

Comment: in CollectionView cells, it shows only `Сегодня`, and the other weekdays leaves blank

Comment: var actualDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
if date.isSame(Date()) {
    actualDate = "Today"
}
let day = NSLocalizedString(actualDate, comment: "")
cell.dayCollection.text = day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174545/discussion-between-joe-hart-and-ktang).

Answer (score 5):

I think it is better to use the default localization for dates, instead of a custom localized string.

```
let date = Date() 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let day = dateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized
print(day)  // you will see eg. "Пятница"
```

You can even use `Locale.current` and days will shown
according to the user's device language.